# How to correctly update database when users session expires for ASP.NET web application using the new .NET 6 format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-6.0

When a users session expires I want to update the database to switch their status to offline but I cannot find the right way to do this as I know that they can either close the browser/page or the session could expire. I'm using CookieAuthentication which has a timer of 30 minutes.

I would like some advice on the best way I can do this, either having Javascript but I don't know if this can work with C# to run a database script. I also need this per user to when the user logs in the database updates a table saying they are online and when the user logs out it also updates it saying that user is offline but obviously there is multiple ways a user can be 'Offline'.

I am new to coding in ASP.NET and using .NET Core 6. I'm just looking for some advice on the best way this can be done.

Comment: Sessions aren't actively expired. There's no job that runs to check whether a session expired or not. When a user makes a request the server checks to see whether the user session has expired and redirects the user if it has. A Session is used to cache data, not as a way to identify "online" users

Comment: If you really want to check the online status you can use SignalR or Websockets to keep an active channel to the browser that can be used to push notifications. SignalR uses Websockets itself so it can detect whether a connection has closed

Comment: Another option is to use a scheduled job to check the session storage (database or cache) to check which sessions had no activity for a while.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look into SignalR and for the meantime run some scheduled jobs.

Answer (score 0):

From [How to find if ASP.NET session is expired](https://beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Find-If-Session-Expired.aspx#:%7E:text=Another%20option%20to%20check%20if,value%20like%20in%20previous%20example.)

> How to check if session is expired using ASP.NET code
>
> We'll define expired session as situation when Session.IsNewSession is true (it is a new session), but  session cookie already exists on visitor's computer from previous session. Here is a procedure that returns true if session is expired and returns false if not.
>
> [ C# ]
>
> ```
> public static bool IsSessionExpired()
> {
>   if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
>   {
>     if (HttpContext.Current.Session.IsNewSession)
>     {
>      string CookieHeaders = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
>
>      if ((null != CookieHeaders) && (CookieHeaders.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
>      {
>      // IsNewSession is true, but session cookie exists,
>      // so, ASP.NET session is expired
>      return true;
>      }
>    }
>   }
>
>   // Session is not expired and function will return false,
>   // could be new session, or existing active session
>   return false;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it seems with .NET Core 6 `HttpContext.Current` is no longer a thing.

Comment: @SamBailey Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: The question is how to execute some job when a session expires, not how to detect whether the session has already expired. Session in ASP.NET Core doesn't work that way though - there's no job that checks for active sessions and causes them to expire.